Python Pandas to read_excel but provide NULL where columns expected but not found
I'm using Python 3 with pandas.
Is there a way to read_excel but provide NULL where columns expected are not found?
For example, I'm looping through many workbooks, but sadly, not all the sheets do not have the column 'SEQ ID'. So I'm getting the below error:-
ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['SEQ ID']
df = pd.read_excel(wb_data, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], sheet_name="Premises Evaluation",usecols=['SEQ ID', 'NAME', 'AGE'])

So, is there a clever way to replace the column with NULLs if the column does not exist?

I've got the below working but not sure if it's best practice.
df = pd.read_excel(wb_data, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], sheet_name="Premises Evaluation",usecols=lambda c: c in {'SEQ ID', 'NAME', 'UPRN'})


Yes, I'd say that it is. If you want to add the potentially missing columns, it's perhaps easier to use a list. cols = ['SEQ ID', 'NAME', 'AGE'] and then df = pd.read_excel(..., usecols=lambda c: c in cols).reindex(cols, axis=1), preserving order with any missing column added with NaN values. But maybe you want to concat these dfs. In that case you don't really need that at an intermediate level.
